# How to fetch other data using the arguments?

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase

I passed arguments to next page, and I'm trying to fetch other data using arguments in flutter.

I'm using supabase, the data I'm trying to fetch is thumbNailUrl.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
  '/postScreen',
  arguments: postId,
);
```

| post_id(int) | thumbNailUrl(String) |
| --- | --- |
| ~~~ | ~~~ |

But I cannot understand how to fetch thumbNailUrl using arguments, and I want to enter parameters into postImage().

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          postImage( ~ ),
          .
          .
          .
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Please help me,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I barely solve it,, hope it helps others to use supabase and dart.

```
// previous_screen.dart

Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
  '/postScreen',
  arguments: postId,
);
```

```
// post_screen.dart

Future fetchData(int postId) async {
  final data = await Supabase.instance.client
    .from('board')
    .select('thumbnail_url, title')
    .eq('post_id', postId)
    .single();

  final result = [
    data['thumbnail_url'],
    data['title'],
  ];
  return result;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final postId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as int; // use this type carefully.
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: fetchData(postId),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      final thumbNailUrl = snapshot.data[0];
      final title = snapshot.data[1];
      return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          YourWidget(thumbNailUrl, title),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
      '/postScreen',

      ///
      /// Arugments type is a Object? so you can pass any type of data
      /// - String
      /// - int
      /// - double
      /// - bool
      /// - List
      /// - Map
      /// - Class
      /// - Enum
      /// - etc...
      ///
      arguments: AnyClass(1, ''),
    );
```

**PostScreen**

```
    ///
    /// Here /PostScreen
    ///
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;

    if (args is AnyClass) {
      print(args.postId);
      print(args.postImageUrl);
    }
```

**AnyClass**

This is an example you should create a new one for yourself

```
final class AnyClass {
  AnyClass(this.postId, this.postImageUrl);
  final int postId;
  final String postImageUrl;
}
```

Source: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments